# Custom styling of tags using the elements-plus select multiple packs in Vue 3

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, element-plus

After a good scrape of the web I am close to resolved that there is no nice way of doing this with the package we are using but I turn to you as a last hurrah!

The package in use is [element-plus](https://element-plus.org/en-US/), and the component my question relates to is the [Select](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/select.html#basic-multiple-select) component, specifically with the flag multiple.

Logically, this works exactly as expected this question is %100 about styling.

Code below:

```
  <el-select
    v-model="specialistsData"
    multiple
    filterable
    remote
    reserve-keyword
    placeholder="Please type a specialist name"
    remote-show-suffix
    :remote-method="remoteMethodSpecalist"
    :loading="loading"
    :disabled="isShowAllSpecialist"
    @change="filterSpecialists"
  >
    <el-option
      v-for="item in options"
      :key="item.value"
      :label="item.label"
      :value="item.value"
    />
  </el-select>
```

Is it possible to style the tags in the multiselect? I know you can style the dropdown items  using the `<el-option>`, but we need to style the actual select tags, conditionally per item. See dreadful snipping tool picture for example. ANY ideas welcomed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's unclear to me what exactly you're after, plus element-plus doesn't seem to provide a any way to pass properties to the tag elements.

However, if you're ok using the order (background not tied to select) you could use `nth-child()` css selector

```html
<style>
  .el-select .el-select__tags .el-tag--info:nth-child(1){
    background-color: khaki;
  }
  .el-select .el-select__tags .el-tag--info:nth-child(2){
    background-color: skyblue;
  }
  .el-select .el-select__tags .el-tag--info:nth-child(2) .el-select__tags-text{
    color: darkslateblue;
  }
</style>
```

[example](https://element-plus.run/#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)